# Calling derived class method in base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix, derived

We can call "Base class methods" in derived class. but Can we call derived class method in base class function?

```
#include<iostream.h>

class base {

 public:

   void print()
   {
     cout<<"base class";
   }

};

 class derived : public base

 {

  public:
    void print()
    {

            cout<<"derived class";

    }

 };
```

How to call this derived class `print()` function in Base class?

Comment: Are you looking for virtual functions?

Comment: Base class don't know anything about derived class. Your question is incorrect. Please try to correct your question.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call a *normal* method defined in derived class from base class. What you can do is add a `virtual` (possibly pure) method in base class, provide implementation in derived class. You can call this method from base.

```
class Base{
public:
 virtual void foo(){cout<<"Hello";};
 void bar() { foo();}
};

class Derived: public Base{
 public:
 void foo() override{ cout<<"Hi";}
};

int main() {
 Base* b1 = new Derived();
 b1->bar(); //will call Derived::foo()

 Base* b2=new Base();
 b2->bar(); // will call Base::foo()
}
```

Comment: +1 for `override`. The other possible alternative is CRTP, but that's probably too advanced...

Answer (score 2):

You can call derived class's method from base class method on a derived class object, if it's a **virtual** method:

```
class base {
  public:
    void doSomething() { 
      print();  
    }
    virtual void print() {
      cout<<"base class";
    }
};

class derived : public base {
  public:
    virtual void print() {
      cout<<"derived class";
    }
};

int main() {
  derived d;
  base* pb = &d;
  pb->doSomething();
}
```

It is known as [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: The key here is that `print()` isn't really a derived-class method; it's declared in the base class so all instances (of base or derived) must have it.  The derived class is just providing a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that all instantiations of `base` will be as the base class of `derived` (as might be the case in a use of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern)), you can simply `static_cast` `this` to `derived*`:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
    void call_derived_print();
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"base class";
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
       std::cout<<"derived class";
    }
};

void base::call_derived_print() {
    //undefined behaviour unless the most-derived type of `*this`
    //is `derived` or is a subtype of `derived`.
    static_cast<derived*>(this)->print();
}
```

Comment: to me this is unsafe. the `Base::print` should be *pure virtual*, or use CRTP in proper way. people like to do all kinds of things

Comment: @RakibulHasan: It's perfectly safe as long as the constraints listed in the answer are met. Sometimes you don't want to pay the cost of a virtual call.

Comment: that's the point, *it is safe if constraints are met*, why leave hole? Rather you can go for template.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: Since `base` and `derived` are clearly just dummy names, there is nothing here to say that this won't use CRTP in a proper way. There are already 4 answers mentioning `virtual` functions, which I agree are a better solution in most cases, so there didn't seem to be a need for another answer talking about those. This answer is for if there is some constraint that requires `print` to be non-virtual.